# Problem with using useRef to add cssText in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

I encountered a problem when trying to use `useRef` react hook to add cssText in Typescript. I have tested the code in Javascript and it works perfectly fine but unable to make it work in Typescript. My code is as below. The code will change the background color of a div when I click the button.

```
import {useRef} from 'react';

function App() {
  const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const handleClick = () => {
    divRef.current && divRef.current.style.cssText += "background-color: blue";
  }

  return (
    <div className="App" ref={divRef}>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I got the following error message:

```
ERROR in src/App.tsx
  Line 6:51:  Parsing error: ';' expected

webpack compiled with 2 errors
ERROR in src/App.tsx:6:52
TS1005: ';' expected.
    4 |   const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    5 |   const handleClick = () => {
  > 6 |     divRef.current && divRef.current.style.cssText += "background-color: blue";
      |                                                    ^^
    7 |   };
    8 |
    9 |   return (
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxIre.png)

My dependencies are as below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.33",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Appreciate if anyone can share any insight into this issue.

Comment: Add `;` to the end of this line -  `const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)`, and to the end of the `handleClick` function.

Comment: Hi @OriDrori, thanks for your reply. That didn't help with the error. I have added a screenshot of the error. It was highlighting the ``+=`` sign after cssText.

Comment: Why must you "abuse" short-circuiting for this? A simple if statement would do it justice and make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (divRef.current) {
  divRef.current.style.cssText += 'background-color: blue';
}
```

or

```
divRef.current && (divRef.current.style.cssText += "background-color: blue");
```

because `&&` has precedence over `+=`